# Schema design for a table having one column pointing towards multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Consider the following schema:

```
create schema testSchema;
use testSchema;

create table A (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    name varchar (50),
    primary key(id));

create table B (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    name varchar (50),
    primary key(id));

create table C (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    name varchar (50),
    primary key(id));

create table main (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    typeId int,
    type varchar(50),
    tableMappingsId int,
    primary key (id)
); 

create table tableMappings (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    tableName varchar(50),
    primary key (id)
);

insert into A (name) values 
('usa'),
('uk'),
('uno');

insert into B (name) values 
('earth'),
('mars'),
('jupiter');

insert into C (name) values 
('1211'),
('12543'),
('345');

insert into main (typeId, type, tableMappingsId) values
(1,'tableA',1),
(2,'tableB',2),
(3,'tableC',3);

insert into tableMappings (tableName) values ('A'),('B'),('C');
```

Description:-

I have three tables A, B and C which have id and name.

In main table, type tells from which table (A or B or C) we have to read the name property. typeId tells the id within that table(A or B or C). To do this I have created a tableMappings table which has tableNames. In main table I have created a column tableMappingsId which points to tableMappings.

Is this correct approach? and how can I write a query like following in MySQL:-

select (name property) from the table which is pointed to by this row and mapped by tableMappings?

Comment: Basically, why not to put the name varchar(50) in the main table ? What motivates your design ?

Comment: table A,B and C can have many records and would have multiple other columns inside them also. name property can be varchar(200) or bigger. So basically motivation is same as to why do we use foreign keys.

Comment: So if we think in an object-oriented manner, your have a base class constituted of attributes recorded in main table, and derivated by A, B and C with additionnal attributes ?

Comment: yes main class which has many other other attributes plus X attribute which can be A, B or C

Comment: Ok. I prepare an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About your design**

If we think in an object-oriented manner, your have a base class constituted of attributes recorded in main table, and derivated by A, B and C with additionnal attributes.
You want to avoid having many attributes in a single table with NULLs depending on records types. This is a good approach. But your method to implement this can be improved.

**Answer to your question**

You want to select from a table (A, B or C) depending on the value of a field. As far as I know this cant be done without "preparing" the query.

"preparing" the query can be done in multiple manners :

- using prepared statements ("pure-SQL" method) : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html
- in a stored procedure or function for example : selecting the type, then testing the type and selecting from the right table
- or constituting the query in two times via a script language

Example with prepared statement :

```
SET @idToSelect = 2;

SELECT
    CONCAT('SELECT name FROM ', tableMappings.tableName, ' WHERE Id = ', main.tableMappingsId)
    INTO @statement
    FROM main
        INNER JOIN tableMappings ON tableMappings.tableName = REPLACE(main.type, 'table', '')
    WHERE main.id = @idToSelect;

PREPARE stmt FROM @statement;

EXECUTE stmt;
```

*Note : we have to translate 'tableA', 'tableB'... in main.type to match to 'A', 'B'... in tableMappings.tableName, which is not ideal.*

But this is not very convenient and efficient.

**Other approaches and comments**

***Selecting from multiple tables : not necessarily a big deal***

Basically, you want to avoid SELECT'ing from tables you dont need to read from. But keep in mind that if your schema is correctly indexed, this is not necessarily a big deal. MySQL runs a query optimizer. You could simply LEFT JOIN all of the tables and select from the right table depending on 'type' value :

```
SET @idToSelect = 2;

SELECT
    IFNULL(A.name, IFNULL(B.name, C.name)) AS name

    FROM main
        LEFT JOIN A ON main.type = 'tableA' AND A.id = main.tableMappingsId
        LEFT JOIN B ON main.type = 'tableB' AND B.id = main.tableMappingsId
        LEFT JOIN C ON main.type = 'tableC' AND C.id = main.tableMappingsId

    WHERE main.id = @idToSelect;
```

*Note that I didn't use tableMappings table*

***Useless tableMappings trick***

You can avoid using this kind of mapping by using the same id in the "children" table as in the main table. This is how many ORM's implement inheritance. I will give an example later in my answer.

***A bit irrelevant example***

In your question, you want to select the "name" property regardless of the type of the record. But I bet if you have really different types of records, **each type holds a different set of properties**. If the "name" is a common property between all the types, it should be in the main table. I assume you provided "name" as a simplified example.
But I think in a real case, you'll rarely have to select a field regardless of the type of the object.

Other thing : In data example, you provide records for A, B and C tables which does not match to main records

***Final proposition***

```
drop schema testSchema;
create schema testSchema;
use testSchema;

create table main (
    id int not null auto_increment,
    typeId int,
    common_data VARCHAR(50),
    primary key (id)
);

create table A (
    id int not null,
    specific_dataA varchar (50),
    primary key(id),
    foreign key FK_A (id) references main (id)
);

create table B (
    id int not null,
    specific_dataB varchar (50),
    primary key(id),
    foreign key FK_B (id) references main (id)
);

create table C (
    id int not null,
    specific_dataC varchar (50),
    primary key(id),
    foreign key FK_C (id) references main (id)
);

insert into main (typeId, common_data) values
(1, 'ABC'),
(2, 'DEF'),
(3, 'GHI');

insert into A (id, specific_dataA) values 
(1, 'usa');

insert into B (id, specific_dataB) values 
(2, 'mars');

insert into C (id, specific_dataC) values
(3, '345');
```

Some comments :

- typeId in main table is optionnal, but depending on queries you have to do it could be useful to retrieve the type of an object. One field is enough, dont need typeId integer and type varchar.
- id's in A, B and C tables are not auto_increment because they have to match to main id's
- this design is irrelevant if there is no common attributes, so I put a common data field in main table
- I materialized relations by defining foreign keys

Queries examples :

I want the common data field for id 1 :

```
SELECT common_data FROM main WHERE id = 1;
```

I know that id 2 is from type B and I want the specific data B :

```
SELECT specific_dataB FROM B WHERE id = 2;
```

I know that id 3 is from type C and I want the common data and the specific data C :

```
SELECT common_data, specific_dataB FROM main INNER JOIN B ON B.id = main.id WHERE main.id = 2;
```

(best match to your case) I dont know the type of object 3 but I want a specific data depending on its type :

```
SELECT IFNULL(
    A.specific_dataA,
    IFNULL(
        B.specific_dataB,
        C.specific_dataC
    )
)
FROM main
    LEFT JOIN A on A.id = main.id
    LEFT JOIN B on B.id = main.id
    LEFT JOIN C on C.id = main.id
WHERE main.id = 3
```